# Rails server always crashing no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails server is always crashing (Ruby console)
I am using windows 7 and I dont get any error in the console. Just an windows error telling my the ruby console how stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be great if you add more information about version of Ruby you're using (`ruby -v`), Version of Rails (saying version 3 is not enough) and any more specific on your settings, like if you're using a MySQL database and how you're connecting to it.

So far, I can point you the the following resources:

Incorrect usage of MySQL library (libmysql.dll) can result in random crashes of Ruby/Rails. [See manual installation and compilation steps here](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/)

There is a known issue with Ruby 1.9.2 that make it crash on concurrent/multiple threads, reported in [Ruby bug tracker #3840](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/3840). It was not solved in 1.9.2-p290 but is part of Ruby 1.9.3 (due to release in August)

Again, those are the two thing that I can think of based on the scarce information you provided. Please update your question with more details (the `development.log` file inside log directory should contain something) or even the output that is displayed prior the crash in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest checking Windows event log and/or ROR logs. Also, what version of ROR are you running?

Comment: I removed some caching and did delete my log and created a new one, the old one was 101 MB!